# how to make child component update when form in parent component submit

Tags: reactjs

Hi I've been at this for two days now and is not getting any solution or answers. It is getting on my nerves and frustrating.

What I am trying to do is to update the list in child component after I hit submit that POST to the db on my api server. The child component is print a list of all records from the DB. When I submit, the child should re-render that list all the record from DB including the one just submitted.
I had to hit page refresh to get the list updated including the newly posted record. I don't want to refresh the page. Just the list (child) component.

I tried every possible solution from Stackoverflow, Google, etc.

Im using React 16.10.

See the entire code below. Tell me what I need to change to make it work.

Im getting headache. Im going to get Tylenol after I post this questions.

Ill start with app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import './App.css';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import TaskList from './components/tasklist';
import EditTask from './components/listEdit';
import CreateList from './components/listCreate';

class App extends Component {
  render() { 
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navigation />
          <div className="container">
            <Route path="/" exact component={TaskList} />
            <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditTask} />
            <Route path="/create" component={CreateList} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

listCreate.js (parent component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TaskList from './tasklist';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class CreateList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onChangeListStatus = this.onChangeListStatus.bind(this);
        this.onChangeListItem = this.onChangeListItem.bind(this);
        this.onChangeListDue = this.onChangeListDue.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            list_status: '',
            list_item: '',
            list_due: '',
            list_created: ''
        }
    }

    onChangeListStatus(e) {
        this.setState({
            list_status: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeListItem(e) {
        this.setState({
            list_item: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeListDue(e) {
        this.setState({
            list_due: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(`Form submitted:`);
        console.log(`Item Status: ${this.state.list_status}`);
        console.log(`Item: ${this.state.list_item}`);
        console.log(`Item Due: ${this.state.list_due}`);

        const newItem = {
            list_status: this.state.list_status,
            list_item: this.state.list_item,
            list_due: this.state.list_due,
        };

        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/lists/add', newItem)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));

        this.setState({
            list_status: '',
            list_item: '',
            list_due: '',
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <div style={{marginTop: 10}}>
                <h3>Create New Item</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group"> 
                        <label>New Item: </label>
                        <input  type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.list_item}
                                onChange={this.onChangeListItem}
                                />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Due Date: </label>
                        <input 
                                type="text" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.list_due}
                                onChange={this.onChangeListDue}
                                />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Status: </label>
                        <input 
                                type="text" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.list_status}
                                onChange={this.onChangeListStatus}
                                />
                    </div>        
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create Item" className="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <TaskList reload={"true"}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

tasklist.js (child)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ItemRow from './itemRow';
import ItemField from './itemField';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class TaskList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  refreshlist: '',
                        lists: []
                    };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({ data: nextProps.data });  
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/lists/')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ lists: response.data });
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    // componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    //     this.setState(this.state)
    //   }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (nextProps.total !== prevState.total) {
          return (this.setState({ refreshlist: nextProps.refreshlist })) // <- this is setState equivalent
        }
        // etc...
      }


    listoftask() {
        return this.state.lists.map(function(currentItem, i){
            return <ItemRow list={currentItem} key={i} />;
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }} >
                    <thead>
                        <ItemField />
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        { this.listoftask() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

update:
This is the api server i use to send data from db

```
// const dotenv = require("dotenv"); 
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
// import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const app = express();
const listRoutes = express.Router();

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const URI_lists = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/lists';

let List = require('./models/task');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

mongoose.connect(URI_lists, 
                {useNewUrlParser: true,
                 useUnifiedTopology: true},
                )
        .then(() => {
            console.log("MongoDB database initial connection established successfully.");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("ERROR! Could not connect to Database!");
            console.log(err);
        });

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.on('disconnected',()=> {console.log('lost connection!')});
connection.on('reconnected',()=> {console.log('reconnected to db again!')});


listRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    List.find(function(err, lists) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(lists);
        }
    });
});

listRoutes.route('/:id').get(function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    List.findById(id, function(err, list) {
        res.json(list);
    });
});

listRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function(req, res) {
    List.findById(req.params.id, function(err, list) {
        if (!list)
            res.status(404).send("data is not found");
        else
            list.list_item = req.body.list_item;
            list.list_status = req.body.list_status;
            list.list_due = req.body.list_due;
            list.list_created = req.body.list_created;

            list.save().then(list => {
                res.json('List item updated!');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("Update not possible");
            });
    });
});

listRoutes.route('/add').post(function(req, res) {
    let newitem = new List(req.body);
    newitem.save()
        .then(list => {
            res.status(200).json({'list': 'list item added successfully'});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new list item failed');
        });
});

app.use('/lists', listRoutes);

app.listen( PORT, () => { 
    console.log('Server is running on Port: ' + PORT);
});
```

here's my repo on GitHub:

(backend) https://github.com/zenkbaries/todoList
(frontend) https://github.com/zenkbaries/todolistapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Child component will re-render when updated props are passed to it. Otherwise it has no need to update.

Looking at your configuration, the Child component only has one prop, and it never changes. Also, the only time you would actually retrieve the updated data from your API is in `componentDidMount()`, which only triggers after the first initial mount of the component.

For your functionality to work as expected, you'll need to pass in an updated prop each time you submit the form. And upon receiving that update, make a new request to the API.

Without refactoring your code too much, we can do something like this:

In CreateList.js (Parent):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TaskList from './tasklist';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class CreateList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onChangeListStatus = this.onChangeListStatus.bind(this);
        this.onChangeListItem = this.onChangeListItem.bind(this);
        this.onChangeListDue = this.onChangeListDue.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            new_item: {},
            list_status: '',
            list_item: '',
            list_due: '',
            list_created: ''
        }
    }

    onChangeListStatus(e) {
        this.setState({
            list_status: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeListItem(e) {
        this.setState({
            list_item: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeListDue(e) {
        this.setState({
            list_due: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(`Form submitted:`);
        console.log(`Item Status: ${this.state.list_status}`);
        console.log(`Item: ${this.state.list_item}`);
        console.log(`Item Due: ${this.state.list_due}`);

        const newItem = {
            list_status: this.state.list_status,
            list_item: this.state.list_item,
            list_due: this.state.list_due,
        };

        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/lists/add', newItem)
             .then(res => {
                 this.setState({
                     list_status: '',
                     list_item: '',
                     list_due: '',
                     new_item: newItem
                 })
             });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <div style={{marginTop: 10}}>
                <h3>Create New Item</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group"> 
                        <label>New Item: </label>
                        <input  type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.list_item}
                                onChange={this.onChangeListItem}
                                />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Due Date: </label>
                        <input 
                                type="text" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.list_due}
                                onChange={this.onChangeListDue}
                                />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Status: </label>
                        <input 
                                type="text" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.list_status}
                                onChange={this.onChangeListStatus}
                                />
                    </div>        
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create Item" className="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <TaskList newItem={this.state.new_item}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So we have a newItem object that gets passed to the Child. We're simply using that to identify a change.

taskList.js (Child)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ItemRow from './itemRow';
import ItemField from './itemField';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class TaskList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  refreshlist: '',
                        lists: []
                    };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/lists/')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ lists: response.data });
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
         if(prevProps.newItem !== this.props.newItem){
            axios.get('http://localhost:4000/lists/')
                .then(response => {
                     this.setState({ lists: response.data });
                })
                .catch(function (error){
                     console.log(error);
                })
         }
    }

    listoftask() {
        return this.state.lists.map(function(currentItem, i){
            return <ItemRow list={currentItem} key={i} />;
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }} >
                    <thead>
                        <ItemField />
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        { this.listoftask() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In the Child component, we introduce the `componentDidUpdate()` hook which is triggered whenever the child component gets an updated props or state. Then we simply reapply the same logic you had in `componentDidMount()` to fetch the list data.

Comment: Reading it . it makes sense. But when I put that in my code and run it.  No change.  List still not updating.
I now understand that to use `componentDidUpdate()` to make the state change to trigger the update. it makes sense but when I run this code...it has no effect.
Do the trigger suppose to cascade down to child/grandchild component (<ItemRow /> in <TaskList />)?

Comment: @JohnTowery oh darn. Can you see that the API is getting hit on update?

Comment: @JohnTowery actually my bad. I didn't see that your code was behaving asynchronously, the logic to update your state was happening before the actual post request was completing. But I've updated the code above to remedy this. Can you try the above?

Comment: yes!! SOLVED! sheesh.... now i have to keep in mind to use promise.   
Do I use promise AND `componentDidUpdate()`?

Comment: @JohnTowery that's right. you have to update the state of your parent component after the promise has completed. The only way to ensure that is either writing the logic within the `.then` block or using `async/await`. Then because you're updating the state and passing a new prop to the child, `componentDidUpdate()` is triggered. With that in mind, please consider upvoting and marking this as the solution :)